# Most secure way to update database on a site using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, database, security

I am building a site using mod_rewrite, such that it has a tree as below:

```
+---css
|   \---bootplus-responsive.min.css
|   \---bootplus.min.css
|   \---extra.css
+---views
|   \---autolike.php
|   \---controlpanel.php
|   \---footer.php
|   \---header.php
|   \---home.php
\---app.php
\---controller.php
\---model.php
\---router.php
\---.htaccess
```

Each page is put together with /controlpanel consisting of header.php, then controlpanel.php, and finally footer.php etc.

Router.php

```
$this->routes = array(
"home" => "indexPage",
"controlpanel" => "controlPanel",
"autolike" => "autoLike",
"about" => "about",
"logout" => "logout"
);
```

(Relevent part of) Controller.php

```
private function loadView($view){
    require("views/" . $view . ".php");
}
private function loadPage($view){
    $this->loadView("header");
    $this->loadView($view);
    $this->loadView("footer");
}

//--- Page Functions
private function indexPage(){
    $this->loadPage("home");
}
private function controlPanel(){
    $this->loadPage("controlpanel");
}
private function autoLike(){
    $this->loadPage("autolike");
}
private function about(){
    $this->loadPage("about");
}
```

app.php

```
require("controller.php);
$app = new Controller();
```

It works as such that pages are actually displayed at app.php?page=[page] and then mod_rewrite shortens it to /[page]/ etc, I hope you understand so far!

On controlpanel.php there is a form that gets populated with information from the database on page load, and then there is a submit button to update the data. I cannot think of a way to securely update data because if I (for example) create update.php and then send the data with GET, anyone could just go to update.php?username=[not their username]&email=[some email] etc and change anyone elses records. POST does not seem to work with mod_rewrite as well. Can anyone give me any advice?

TL;DR: How do I securely send information from a form to a database when mod_rewrite is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

- GET vs. POST doesn't matter here, neither protects anything more than the other
- GET vs. POST is only semantical and has certain different behavioral specifications for clients, it's not a security measure
- mod_rewrite works just fine with POST requests
- all mod_rewrite does it to intercept and modify which physical file gets executed in response to a URL, nothing more, nothing less

What you want is an **authentication and permission system**. Require users to be logged in. Establish permissions on what a user can and cannot do or access. **Check for every single request whether the user is allowed what he's about to do.** If he POSTs to `update.php?username=foobar`, check whether he is allowed to change anything about username `foobar` and deny the request is he isn't.